# using php to get videos from twitter

Tags: php, video, twitter

Been looking for a while now so it's time to ask. How is it I can get the twitter videos in my custom php feed. I can pull in the photos urls no problem using something like..

```
$tweet->entities->media[0]->media_url;
```

But I cannot find a solution to get a user feeds video url, or even a poster image url for the video would be great too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a tweet fetched using search/tweets saved in **$tweet**

```
// Check if tweet has media
if (!empty($tweet->entities->media)) {
    $searchArray = array(
        "id" => $tweet->id, // id of the tweet we just fetched
        "include_entities" => true // tells twitter API to return videos and stuff
    );

    // Get extended_entities
    $extendedEntities = $connection->get("statuses/show", $searchArray);
    foreach($extendedEntities->extended_entities->media as $media){
        var_dump($media->video_info->variants);
    }
}
```

**Example result**

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[265]
      public 'bitrate' => int 832000
      public 'content_type' => string 'video/webm' (length=10)
      public 'url' => string 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/560049056895209473/pu/vid/480x480/gj_fzyk29R9dMPBY.webm' (length=92)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[266]
      public 'bitrate' => int 832000
      public 'content_type' => string 'video/mp4' (length=9)
      public 'url' => string 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/560049056895209473/pu/vid/480x480/gj_fzyk29R9dMPBY.mp4' (length=91)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[267]
      public 'bitrate' => int 1280000
      public 'content_type' => string 'video/mp4' (length=9)
      public 'url' => string 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/560049056895209473/pu/vid/720x720/S7F4BF2wKR2txCpA.mp4' (length=91)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[268]
      public 'content_type' => string 'application/dash+xml' (length=20)
      public 'url' => string 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/560049056895209473/pu/pl/udxtIM8FytsAE4HQ.mpd' (length=82)
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[269]
      public 'bitrate' => int 320000
      public 'content_type' => string 'video/mp4' (length=9)
      public 'url' => string 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/560049056895209473/pu/vid/240x240/v5jqpUNnkaeuVZbx.mp4' (length=91)
  5 => 
    object(stdClass)[270]
      public 'content_type' => string 'application/x-mpegURL' (length=21)
      public 'url' => string 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/560049056895209473/pu/pl/udxtIM8FytsAE4HQ.m3u8' (length=83)
```

Answer (score 1):

when searching use '**filter=videos**'
example call can be:

```
?q=#dog&result_type=recent&count=20&filter=videos&include_entities=true
```

video url: *https://t.co/u9Yaulk7Nz*
see the response bellow:

```
[urls] => Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [url] => https://t.co/u9Yaulk7Nz
            [expanded_url] => https://vine.co/v/O2T90LHOwV6
            [display_url] => vine.co/v/O2T90LHOwV6
            [indices] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 97
                    [1] => 120
                )

        )

)
```

Example of HTML

```
<a href="https://vine.co/v/O2T90LHOwV6"><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/571566115719004160/pu/img/H8GR0a02w_vAzUjr.jpg:thumb"></a>
```

I hope will help.